# ObservableCollection Move throws Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a ObservableCollection bound to a ListView.
Inside the ListView, I have two buttons in the ItemTemplate, move up and move down. The MoveUp button will move the item one place in the ObservableCollection using ObservableCollection.Move:

```
private void MoveUp(DataItem dataItem)
{
    var index = SubMissions.IndexOf(dataItem);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        DataItems.Move(index, index - 1);
    }
}
```

This works fine when I move one item up from the bottom to the top.

However, when I click Move Up on the last item, it will move up as expected. But, when I click Move up on the item that has then become the last one, it fails with exception

```
 Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index, Int32 oldIndex)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.MoveItem(Int32 oldIndex, Int32 newIndex)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.Move(Int32 oldIndex, Int32 newIndex)
```

And, not only for the last one. If I click Up on the second item, it works fine. Click on Up on the new second item, fails.
I've confirmed that the value of index is correct. E.g. I can reproduce the error by calling DataItems.Move(1,0) twice in a row.

My XAML is:

```
<ListView x:Name="DataItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                <Button Content="MOVE UP" Command="{Binding ViewModel.MoveUpCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                <Button Content="MOVE DOWN" Command="{Binding ViewModel.MoveDownCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

The Locator is a static object which use SimpleIoc. Courtesy of MVVMLight.net.

/Edit: I found out that when I run .Move(1,0) in e.g. a different method it's working fine. So it must be that I'm changing the collection inside a command?
But how should I do it then? And why does it work the first time?

Comment: I have tested with my ObservableCollection for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                OC.Move(OC.Count() - 1, OC.Count() - 2);
            } and it does not fail at all, might be is there something else?

Comment: Yes, it only fails in my command. Must be XAML related. But what is wrong with my XAML? Only guess is that the buttons are bound to the DataItem? But why does it only fail the second time?
And why are XAML / binding errors still so useless...

Comment: Or should I use a CollectionViewSource instead, as I read some issues regarding ObserableCollections bindings?

Comment: Forget CollectionViewSource for this in my opinion, DataItems is an observablecollection<class> isn't it? Can you show the commands? just to find a clue?

Comment: The command code is in the start post (i.e. MoveUp). I'm binding that method to a RelayCommand (part of MvvmLight), which is bound to MOVE UP button in my XAML (see also start post).

And yes, DataItems is just an ObservableCollection.

Comment: So it only goes wrong when I e.g. click once MOVEUP on the last item, and then again MOVE UP on what's then the last item. This means that the order is back to the original order. Probably that's causing issues? I.e. binding to a previous instance? Don't know, XAML sometimes is weird.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve this?